# Confusion about expression for length contraction of rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

My physics book states that in the construction in the figure, if the event C has coordinates x'= 0 and t' = l in the primed frame, then event C has x -coordinate in the unprimed frame:

$$x_C = \frac{l}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$
[image: The angle between t and t' should be the same as between x and x' are the same. The slope of the world line of the rear of the rod and the front of the rod are the same. Sorry about my iffy picture.]
When I try to derive the expression myself I don't get this answer. 
Using the invariance of the interval at C:

$$-t² + x² = -t'² + x'² = l²$$

Dividing by $x²$ on both sides and rearranging:

$$\frac{x²}{x²} = \frac{l²}{x²} + \frac{t²}{x²} \leftrightarrow$$
$$1 = \frac{l²}{x²}+\frac{1}{v²} \leftrightarrow$$
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{v^2} = \frac{l²}{x²} \leftrightarrow$$
$$x²= \frac{l²}{1-\frac{1}{v²}} \rightarrow$$
$$x = \frac{l}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{v²}}}$$

If someone could point me to where I'm going wrong I'd be really grateful. I've been stuck on this for a while. The book is Schutz chapter 1 (Lorentz Contraction).

Comment: In dividing both sides by $x^2$ and going from your second equation to your third equation, why do you assume $\nu = x/t$?

Comment: My book states that the tangent of the angle between the t and t' axis is the velocity of the primed frame. The angle is the same between the x and x'-axis (although that might not be obvious in my figure), so the tangent of this angle should also be the velocity since they are identical. The tangent of the angle is x/t. Oh nonono - it isn' - it is t/x ! Thanks Samuel!

Comment: That solved my problem - if you want write it as an answer and I will accept it, otherwise I can write it out. Thanks!

Comment: I see that the question was put on hold, and I read the guide-lines now. Apart from tagging it 'homework-and-exercises' I don't think there is much to change - the question was more about getting help to find a 'bug' in my calculations than about deeper understanding, so I am fine with it being closed or moved to the correct forum - and really happy for the help!